# How to format HTML code in VS Code on Ubuntu?

Tags: html, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, formatting

I have installed the prettier extension on VS Code and use this shortcut - `Ctrl`+`shift`+ `I`. But it doesn't work for me.

Also tried this- Setting the VSCode preference `html.format.wrapAttributes` to `force`. But nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

If "Format Document" is what you are referring to, you just have to press <kbd>F1</kbd> and search for `Format Document` or just press <kbd>Shift + Alt + F</kbd>

Comment: I mean formatting of code like proper indentations by selecting the code lines using shortcut commands.

Comment: Shift + Alt + F is the shortcut to format a html document at least on VS Code Windows version. It does the indent to your entire code just by using this option

Comment: Yes, I tried this but it is not working for VS Code on Ubuntu.